# Passing values to arrays in a class (C++)

Tags: c++

Trying to learn C++ and came across OOP. I don
t grasp how strncpy(m_strName, strName, 25); works. Isn't this a function? Where is it calling from? I see that it is calling m_strName by pointing through *strName, but how are the values being passed here?

source: [program tutorial](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/82-classes-and-class-members/)

```
#include <iostream>
class Employee
{
public:
    char m_strName[25];
    int m_nID;
    double m_dWage;

    // Set the employee information
    void SetInfo(char *strName, int nID, double dWage)
    {
        strncpy(m_strName, strName, 25);
        m_nID = nID;
        m_dWage = dWage;
    }

    // Print employee information to the screen
    void Print()
    {
        using namespace std;
        cout << "Name: " << m_strName << "  Id: " << 
            m_nID << "  Wage: $" << m_dWage << endl; 
    }
};

int main()
{
    // Declare two employees
    Employee cAlex;
    cAlex.SetInfo("Alex", 1, 25.00);

    Employee cJoe;
    cJoe.SetInfo("Joe", 2, 22.25);

    // Print out the employee information
    cAlex.Print();
    cJoe.Print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is the tutorial using C strings when the purpose isn't to learn about C strings? It also ignores const-correctness, and not using member initializer lists from the get-go is a real shame.

Answer (score 1):

> `char * strncpy ( char * destination, const char * source, size_t num )`
>
> Copies the first num characters of source to destination. If the end of the source C string (which is signaled by a null-character) is found before num characters have been copied, destination is padded with zeros until a total of num characters have been written to it.

`strncpy(m_strName, strName, 25);` will copy 25 characters from `strName` to `m_strName`. This function resides in the `cstring` header file. You will have to include this file in order to use this function.

If you understand this, you will realise that most of your questions don't make sense.

Comment: Makes sense now. They never clarified that it was calling this cstring header file. Why I asked if this was a function. Thanks.

Comment: It is not calling the cstring header file. `strncpy(m_strName, strName, 25);` calls the function `strncpy` which resides inside `cstring` header file. `strncpy(m_strName, strName, 25);` is a function call. Header files cannot be called. Functions are called.